# Question about the relationship between the variance of residuals and variances of the data points

Tags: regression

I was reading about regression. I understand one of the how the variance of each $x_i$ needs to be normal distributed, but why doesn't that related to the $s_b$? It seems like it should. I was reading the AP College Board paper about Inference.

> Two more assumptions are that the errors are normally distributed and that they have
>   the same standard deviation for all x values. Although it is not at all obvious, this is
>   not the same as saying that the residuals are normally distributed and all have the same
>   standard deviation. The difference is that the “errors” are the deviations between the
>   response variables and the “actual” underlying (invisible) linear phenomenon, whereas
>   the “residuals” are the deviations between the response variables and the least-squares
>   regression line, which is only an estimate of the “actual” line.

I understand (I think) that just because the error of the regression is normal doesn't mean that the variance of $x_i$ is normal because the sample could just randomly follow normality.  (don't know if I said that statistically correct), but if all the $x_i$ are normal and the variance are equal, then why doesn't that variance equal the variance that one would get for the $\beta$

I have gotten some great answers here that are very clear and I am hoping that I could get another answer to help clear up my confusion.

The kernel of my question is **What exactly is the relationship between the variance of the residuals and the $x_i$ and is there any connection to the *error, variance* of $\beta$**

[image: the graph]

Comment: Can you clarify your notation? What is $x_i$? In standard notation used for regression, the variance of $x_i$ is never an issue and never discussed.

Comment: @user765195 $x_i$ is the collection of possible data points for a certain value of $x$.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't clarify much. Does $x_i$ have the same meaning that @Scortchi has assumed? (which is the standard meaning, by the way) or is it something else? If it is the standard meaning, then the variance of the $x_i$ has no relevance in the regression, and if not, you have to write your regression equation in full and clarify what its elements are.

Comment: @user765195 I will try to explain to you the best I can, please understand that my knowlege is poor.  Each $x$ has to be normally distributed and when you thinking about the population the variance of the population regression line shouldn't it be related to the variance of each $x$.  Think of a loaf of bread and you slice it, now each slice has its own variance, but combained they form the variance of the regression line, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $x$? (Sorry, I didn't get the bread-slicing analogy.)

Comment: @Scortchi You know the graphs they show you of a regression line with the normal graph extended outward towards you to show, that is where I got the bread slicing idea.  If, each $x_i$ is normal,then why isn't the variablity of the regression line normal because of that?

Comment: Perhaps you could post a link to such a graph.

Comment: Thanks. That graph is showing the distribution of each $y_i$ around $\alpha + \beta x_i$ - a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$. It's certainly *not* showing a normal distribution of the $x_i$'s- there are just three *fixed* values: $x_1$, $x_2$, & $x_3$.

Comment: @Scortchi so the variance of $x_i$ has nothing to do with the variation of the regression line?

Comment: If you're setting the values of a given number $x$'s & you choose them with a larger variance (i.e. more spread out), then the variance of the estimated slope $\hat{\beta}$ will be smaller. If you're sampling them from a population, then the larger the variance of that population, the more likely you are to have a smaller variance of $\hat{\beta}$, though the actual variance of $\hat{\beta}$ will depend on how the sample variance of the $x$'s turns out in that particular sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the text you quote is saying is that in a regression model like

$$y_i=\alpha +\beta x_i +\varepsilon_i$$

whereas the true errors are given by

$$\varepsilon_i=y_i-\alpha-\beta x_i$$

the residuals are estimates of the errors given by

$$\hat{\varepsilon}_i=y_i-\hat{y}_i=y_i-\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta} x_i$$

If the errors are correctly assumed to be independently distributed according to an Normal distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, that assumption doesn't hold for the residuals. Look up Studentization of residuals for more info.

What you seem to be asking is about the variance of the independent variable $X$.  The regression model is fitted conditional on whatever $x_i$ you happen to set, or to observe, so the distribution of $X$, even if it is a random variable, doesn't affect the validity of the regression model. The particular arrangement of the predictors $x_i$ will affect the variance of the residuals, but not the errors, through the hat matrix - residuals at extreme predictor values will tend to have smaller variance. It will also effect the variance of the coefficient estimates $\alpha$ & $\beta$ through the information matrix - a bigger spread of predictor values determines the coefficients more accurately.