# What is the difference between Noise, error and residuals?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, residuals, error, kalman-filter, noise

I was reading about Kalman filter.  http://web.mit.edu/kirtley/kirtley/binlustuff/literature/control/Kalman%20filter.pdf

They talk about additive noise and error. I need to understand difference between noise, error and residuals.

Did some research like-
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Whats_the_difference_between_noise_and_error_in_a_dataset2  and other answers on Stackexchange like-
[What is the difference between errors and residuals?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133389/what-is-the-difference-between-errors-and-residuals)

Can someone please explain me these 3 by talking regression or ARMA model as example?