# Understanding uncorrelated errors assumption in OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals

One of the assumptions of the OLS is that observations of the error terms should not be correlated with each other.
This assumption is often denoted as $\text{Corr}(\epsilon_i,\epsilon_j) = 0$.

The confusion I have is the following:
if $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ are errors, this should mean that they are numbers, and therefore their correlation should always be zero.
If I got it wrong and $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ are random variables, please explain why they are.

Comment: Residuals are numbers. Errors are random variables. It is a slang to use those words interchangeably. Cross Validated must have a good post about residuals vs errors. I’ll see if I can find one.

Comment: [This was the top hit on Google.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133389/what-is-the-difference-between-errors-and-residuals)

Comment: I am confused about your confusion. What do you mean with *"this should mean that they are numbers, and therefore their correlation should always be zero"*. Why should numbers not be able to be correlated? E.g the number of ice cream sales in an ice cream stand on the beach and the number of people/visitors on that beach are numbers: are they not correlated? In a game roulette, the number of time we have red and the number of times we have black are numbers: are they not (negatively) correlated?